# Change HTML image into a Button for partial refresh of page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to webpage design and MVC.  I have a aspx page and I have a html image.  I want to change this image and make it clickable so that it will refresh only the bottom half of the page when clicked. I setup my image so that the source of the image is updated by the controller.  By using the following

```
         src="<%=ViewData["BookImg"] %>"
```

So that the whole story is clear.  When a person clicks on the image of the book, it displays on the bottom half of the page information about that book pulled from a sql database.  I am thinking that I would need to look into getting ajax implemented so that I can do partial page update.  But the question is how do I change that HTML image into a button. Thanks in advance.

---updating per the answer chosen but still having problems---
home.aspx

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("HomePartialView"); %>


  <img id = "Book_Img"  src="<%=ViewData["BookImg"] %>" alt = "click Me" class="imgClick"/>


  <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".imgClick").click(function () {
          $("#HomePartialView").load("@Url.Action("PartialViewBook","HomeController")");
               });
                 });
                </script>
```

---HomeController.cs

```
public ActionResult PartialViewBook()
{
    ViewData[imageBookPressd] = "hello world";
    return View("HomePartialView"); 

 }
```

---update I am still having issues. My controller file sits in Controllers/HomeController.cs in the standard MVC model.  My Home.aspx pages sits in Views/Home/Home.aspx.  I get no errors, and not sure how to debug on script..

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the image to call some javascript when it is clicked, then you can use the following:

`<img src="<%=ViewData["BookImg"] %>" onclick="doSomething();"/>`

However, if you want the image to be a form's Submit button, you will need to change the image to be an 'input' of 'image' type, such as the following link describes:

`<input type="image" src="<%=ViewData["BookImg"] %>" alt="Submit button">`

There's some more info on that here:
http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/using_an_image_as_a_submit_button.php3

Answer (score 1):

you dont need to convert that to a button. You can bind a function on the image for onclick to do your partial page update

Assuming you have the HTML markup for an image like this with the div to be reloaded with partial content

```
<img src="someimage.gif" id="imgReloader" />
<div id="divPartial" ></div>
```

And have this script

```
$(function(){

  $("#imgReloader").click(function(){
    $("#divPartial").load("yourcontroller/youraction");      
 });    
});
```

Now when user clicks on the image, it will call the `youraction` method present in `yourcontroller` and load the result into the div with id `divPartial`

**EDIT : As per the comment,**

If you want to do this in multiple button, you can not use the ID selector as it ID's will be  ( and should be ) unique for the elements. You can give a css class to all those elements and access using that.

```
<img src="someimage.gif" id="imgReloader1" class="imgClick" />
<img src="anotherimage.gif" id="imgReloader2" class="imgClick"  />
```

Now change your script to use the class selector

```
$(function(){    
  $(".imgClick").click(function(){
    $("#divPartial").load("yourcontroller/youraction");      
 });    
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

**EDIT :** To Avoid Path Problems, Always use Ur.Action HTML Helper method instead o hardcoding

```
$("#divPartial").load('@Url.Action("youraction","yourcontroller")');
```

Comment: Okay scripting is new to me, let me do some research.  What if i have multiple images that I want to do the same thing with would i need to create multiple scripts

Comment: okay i am doing the reading on scripting let me ask you this question.  Say I have 3 images on the page 1 image is the book details. The 2nd image is the author information. 3rd image is more a plus sign that shows related books.  This of course would require 3 different scripts am I right? (I promise this is my last question about this :))

Comment: nope.you can use the same script. but change the url for the load method.you can do it by checking the id or you can store the url as an  attribut to the element and read that and replace that as target url. Or you can use `<a>` element and apply css to use your image. in that case, you have a href tag which you can use. if you use this approach. make sure to return false at the end of tour load call other wise it will execute the typical link click behaviour( it will nagigate to that page)

Comment: @ShyjuThanks that makes some sense, only because I am new to scripting that I am not 100%, on exactly how to do that. When i mean "that" i mean changing the URL for the load method, by checking the ID of the img in the script.

Comment: i am still having some trouble on this...i wrote the script as follow <script type="text/javascript"> $(function(){    
  $(".imgClick").click(function(){
  $("#LoadbookPartialView").load("HomeController/PartialViewBook");      
 });    
});   Nothing happens

Comment: @user990951: Are you sure that you have an Action called PartialViewBook in your Home controller ? I guess it is a path problem. Use firebug to see what path it trying to load from. You may need to add ../In front of Home controller or use `@Url.Action` Html helper

Comment: @user990951: you have to use " to separate the parameters of your Ur.Action method. Check the example in my answer. Are you getting any script error ? or the controller being hit ? Use firebug to debug script errors (console tab in firebug for script errors, net tabe to see what ajax call is being invoked) and  visual studio breakpoints to debug your action method.

Comment: it tells me that "PartialViewBook" expected ',' or ')'

Comment: @user990951 there is some syntax errors. change the double quotes to single quote in load method and see

Comment: just tried that and got no errors now, but still nothing is happening when i click the img.

Comment: I have tried the other way with only one image by calling the id out like you show in  your example but again it does nothing

Comment: Thanks for your help what code you want to look at? i pasted all the stuff up there. I am using the MVC model.  My controller is located in Controllers/HomeControllers.cs my View is located in Views/Home/Home.aspx as a HomePartialView.ascx page. My javascript is up there and so is how my image is laid out. in the image should i be referencing onclick = "myFunction" and define myFunction in javascript?